# remove strings and numbers after new line character in list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list.

```
mylist = [[
    ['K', 'X', 'Y'],
    ['1', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
    ['2', '351846.066', '4521086.924'],
    ['3', '351873.561', '4521010.066'],
    ['4', '351922.38', '4521027.586'],
    ['5', '351923.346', '4521027.937'],
    ['6', '351880.618', '4521159.601'],
    ['7', '351877.79', '4521159.243'],
    ['8', '351868.626', '4521159.13'],
    ['9', '351832.0', '4521158.375'],
    ['10', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
    ['K', 'X', 'Y'],
    ['1', '352818.88899999997', '4512961.064277913'],
    ['2', '352818.7852508776', '4512961.008231428'],
    ['3', '352818.1413800079', '4512961.541700357'],
    ['4', '352818.13964983355', '4512961.542853194'],
    ['5', '352818.13771866815', '4512961.543623349'],
    ['6', '352818.13566998736', '4512961.543977531'],
    ['7', '352818.13359234604', '4512961.54390043'],
    ['8', '352818.1315755511', '4512961.54339538'],
    ['9', '352818.1297067792', '4512961.54248421'],
    ['10', '352807.6488787196', '4512955.003591482'],
    ['11', '352804.8280548779', '4512953.398691706'],
    ['12', '352804.8263759837', '4512953.397491489'],
    ['', '13', '352804.8249792202', '4512953.395972193', ''],
    [None, '14', '352804.82392407843', '4512953.394198529', None],
    [None, '15', '352804.82325549907', '4512953.3922460405', None],
    [None, '16', '352804.8230019582', '4512953.390197889', None],
    [None, '17', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n023 14:38', None],
    [None, '19', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n23 14:39', None],
    [None, '20', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n 14:40', None],
    [None, '21', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n15:38', None],
    ['22', '352818.7707811786', '4512961.225168891'],
    ['23', '352818.7722922728', '4512961.224177455'],
    ['K', 'X', 'Y'],
    ['1', '352748.814', '4512151.882'],
    ['2', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
    ['3', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
    ['4', '352833.26206323004', '4512074.104626368'],
    ['5', '352859.8678037648', '4512078.776475903'],
    ['6', '352858.816', '4512082.705'],
    ['7', '352837.633', '4512169.397'],
    ['8', '352748.814', '4512151.882'],

    ]]
```

How can I get rid of `\nDate..` and `\n023..` that are after some numbers ?

Also, I want to get rid of `None` and `''` values. So, I want to have only 3 columns (get rid of `K, X, Y` also.

So, I want to use the data from lines :

```
[None, '17', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n023 14:38', None],
[None, '19', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n23 14:39', None],
[None, '20', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n 14:40', None],
[None, '21', '352818.7027811786\nDate: 06/10/2', '4512961.279168891\n15:38', None],
```

but only the columns and numbers:

```
['17', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
['19', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
['20', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
['21', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
```

So, my final list will be:

```
[
    ['1', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
    ['2', '351846.066', '4521086.924'],
    ['3', '351873.561', '4521010.066'],
    ['4', '351922.38', '4521027.586'],
    ['5', '351923.346', '4521027.937'],
    ['6', '351880.618', '4521159.601'],
    ['7', '351877.79', '4521159.243'],
    ['8', '351868.626', '4521159.13'],
    ['9', '351832.0', '4521158.375'],
    ['10', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
    
    ['1', '352818.88899999997', '4512961.064277913'],
    ['2', '352818.7852508776', '4512961.008231428'],
    ['3', '352818.1413800079', '4512961.541700357'],
    ['4', '352818.13964983355', '4512961.542853194'],
    ['5', '352818.13771866815', '4512961.543623349'],
    ['6', '352818.13566998736', '4512961.543977531'],
    ['7', '352818.13359234604', '4512961.54390043'],
    ['8', '352818.1315755511', '4512961.54339538'],
    ['9', '352818.1297067792', '4512961.54248421'],
    ['10', '352807.6488787196', '4512955.003591482'],
    ['11', '352804.8280548779', '4512953.398691706'],
    ['12', '352804.8263759837', '4512953.397491489'],
    ['13', '352804.8249792202', '4512953.395972193'],
    ['14', '352804.82392407843', '4512953.394198529'],
    ['15', '352804.82325549907', '4512953.3922460405'],
    ['16', '352804.8230019582', '4512953.390197889'],
    ['17', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
    ['19', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
    ['20', '352818.702781178', '4512961.279168891],
    ['21', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891],
    ['22', '352818.7707811786', '4512961.225168891'],
    ['23', '352818.7722922728', '4512961.224177455'],
    
    ['1', '352748.814', '4512151.882'],
    ['2', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
    ['3', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
    ['4', '352833.26206323004', '4512074.104626368'],
    ['5', '352859.8678037648', '4512078.776475903'],
    ['6', '352858.816', '4512082.705'],
    ['7', '352837.633', '4512169.397'],
    ['8', '352748.814', '4512151.882'],

    ]]
```

Comment: how did you generate the list in the first place?

Comment: So you want 2dn 3rd and 5th columns. And you want to split the 3rd and 5th columns by `\n` and get the left side of it?

Comment: Also, why so deeply nested (3-levels)?

Comment: I would use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to get rid of the `None` and `''` entries, then a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to strip out any text after a `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recover all the `['1', '351822.546', '4521159.92']`-like values:

```
out = [[x.split('\n')[0] for x in l if x] # keep leading part
       for l in mylist[0]                 # for each list
       if l[0] != 'K']                    # if the row is not a header
```

Output:

```
[['1', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
 ['2', '351846.066', '4521086.924'],
 ['3', '351873.561', '4521010.066'],
 ['4', '351922.38', '4521027.586'],
 ['5', '351923.346', '4521027.937'],
 ['6', '351880.618', '4521159.601'],
 ['7', '351877.79', '4521159.243'],
 ['8', '351868.626', '4521159.13'],
 ['9', '351832.0', '4521158.375'],
 ['10', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
 ['1', '352818.88899999997', '4512961.064277913'],
 ['2', '352818.7852508776', '4512961.008231428'],
 ['3', '352818.1413800079', '4512961.541700357'],
 ['4', '352818.13964983355', '4512961.542853194'],
 ['5', '352818.13771866815', '4512961.543623349'],
 ['6', '352818.13566998736', '4512961.543977531'],
 ['7', '352818.13359234604', '4512961.54390043'],
 ['8', '352818.1315755511', '4512961.54339538'],
 ['9', '352818.1297067792', '4512961.54248421'],
 ['10', '352807.6488787196', '4512955.003591482'],
 ['11', '352804.8280548779', '4512953.398691706'],
 ['12', '352804.8263759837', '4512953.397491489'],
 ['13', '352804.8249792202', '4512953.395972193'],
 ['14', '352804.82392407843', '4512953.394198529'],
 ['15', '352804.82325549907', '4512953.3922460405'],
 ['16', '352804.8230019582', '4512953.390197889'],
 ['17', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['19', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['20', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['21', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['22', '352818.7707811786', '4512961.225168891'],
 ['23', '352818.7722922728', '4512961.224177455'],
 ['1', '352748.814', '4512151.882'],
 ['2', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
 ['3', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
 ['4', '352833.26206323004', '4512074.104626368'],
 ['5', '352859.8678037648', '4512078.776475903'],
 ['6', '352858.816', '4512082.705'],
 ['7', '352837.633', '4512169.397'],
 ['8', '352748.814', '4512151.882']]
```

#### original answer

Using a simple list comprehension:

```
out = [[l[1], l[2].split('\n')[0], l[3].split('\n')[0]]
       for l in mylist[0]
       # if first item is None and third one contains a \n
       if l[0] is None and '\n' in l[2]]
```

Variant with the walrus operator:

```
out = [[l[1], l2[0], l[3].split('\n')[0]] for l in mylist[0]
       if l[0] is None and len(l2:=l[2].split('\n'))>1]
```

Output:

```
[['17', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['19', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['20', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['21', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891']]
```

This should give you a good starting point to adapt to your exact desired logic.

Comment: At the end, I want all the list elements, not only those with the `\n` etc

Comment: @George that's not what you showed in the expected output, can you provide the full and exact expected output?

Comment: @George I updated the answer with what I think you might want (please refresh the page)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @mozway's answer, you could do:

```
newlist = []

for sub in mylist[0]:
    ss = [s.split("\n")[0] for s in sub if s and s not in ["X", "Y", "K"]]
    if ss:
        newlist.append(ss)
```

With this `newlist` contains:

```
[['1', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
 ['2', '351846.066', '4521086.924'],
 ['3', '351873.561', '4521010.066'],
 ['4', '351922.38', '4521027.586'],
 ['5', '351923.346', '4521027.937'],
 ['6', '351880.618', '4521159.601'],
 ['7', '351877.79', '4521159.243'],
 ['8', '351868.626', '4521159.13'],
 ['9', '351832.0', '4521158.375'],
 ['10', '351822.546', '4521159.92'],
 ['1', '352818.88899999997', '4512961.064277913'],
 ['2', '352818.7852508776', '4512961.008231428'],
 ['3', '352818.1413800079', '4512961.541700357'],
 ['4', '352818.13964983355', '4512961.542853194'],
 ['5', '352818.13771866815', '4512961.543623349'],
 ['6', '352818.13566998736', '4512961.543977531'],
 ['7', '352818.13359234604', '4512961.54390043'],
 ['8', '352818.1315755511', '4512961.54339538'],
 ['9', '352818.1297067792', '4512961.54248421'],
 ['10', '352807.6488787196', '4512955.003591482'],
 ['11', '352804.8280548779', '4512953.398691706'],
 ['12', '352804.8263759837', '4512953.397491489'],
 ['13', '352804.8249792202', '4512953.395972193'],
 ['14', '352804.82392407843', '4512953.394198529'],
 ['15', '352804.82325549907', '4512953.3922460405'],
 ['16', '352804.8230019582', '4512953.390197889'],
 ['17', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['19', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['20', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['21', '352818.7027811786', '4512961.279168891'],
 ['22', '352818.7707811786', '4512961.225168891'],
 ['23', '352818.7722922728', '4512961.224177455'],
 ['1', '352748.814', '4512151.882'],
 ['2', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
 ['3', '352813.891', '4512068.331'],
 ['4', '352833.26206323004', '4512074.104626368'],
 ['5', '352859.8678037648', '4512078.776475903'],
 ['6', '352858.816', '4512082.705'],
 ['7', '352837.633', '4512169.397'],
 ['8', '352748.814', '4512151.882']]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this using functions to make clear code and use regex to take care of every case.

```
def filter_elements(element):
    if not element:
        return None
    if element.isnumeric():
        return element
    if value := re.findall("\d+\.\d+", element):
        return value[0]

def filter_list(sublist):
    out = [new_element for element in sublist if (new_element := filter_elements(element))] 
    if out:
        return out

# use of the functios
final_list = [new_sublist for sublist in mylist if (new_sublist := filter_list(sublist))]
```